# Native navigation bar with transitions

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Is there a way to have native page transitions with an ActionBar/TitleBar in Cordova? (sort of a combination of [cordova-plugin-CDVNavBar](https://github.com/Emadello/cordova-plugin-CDVNavBar) and [cordova-plugin-native-transitions](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-native-transitions) where titles and swipe-back gestures are handled correctly)

To add more details, I'm looking for something that would allow me to:

- Have multiple pages with native transitions
- Keep track of history and be able to go backwards through system gestures/actions
- Custom titles that may change dynamically
- Have some pages have an "action bar" and others be full screen

I have a background in Java and some light android dev. I could port an iOS-only plugin to Java, but I really have no background in iOS or objective C.

Anything in comments to point me in the right direction for finding/starting/hacking a plugin would be appreciated. If worst comes to worst and I have to write my own plugin, I will most likely post it on GitHub and link it here for others to use.

Comment: I can't provide any help with Cordova, but beware thinking that "a background in Java" is necessarily sufficient to set you up for success in Android. Many standard Java API's are absent, and those that are present don't necessarily conform to standard behavior, nor do they necessarily reflect best practice on the platform. Many newcomers find The Android Way of doing things to be quite non-obvious.

Comment: I've dabbled in Android dev - enough to realize how painfully fragmented Android is - but yeah thanks for the warning. Will heed. I switched away from cordova a while ago and paging is the only think keeping me from switching back. I'll go through a few weeks of pain if it saves me a few months of development haha.